# Why does ClassA not keep a reference to ClassC through it's reference to ClassB which is a property of ClassC

Tags: ios, swift, reference

Even though `ClassA` does not have a direct reference to `ClassC`. If we inject the same reference of `b` that `ClassA` has into `ClassC` why does `ClassC` not get retained if it saves this reference to `b`? Why does this only get retained if we create a reference in `ClassA` to `ClassC` directly?

```
class ClassA {
    var b: ClassB?

    func someFunc() {
        let b = ClassB()
        self.b = b
        let c = ClassC(b: b)
        c.doSomething()
    }
}


class ClassB {}

class ClassC {
    private let b: ClassB
    init(b: ClassB) {
        self.b = b
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("doSomething")
    }

    deinit {
        print("C deinit")
    }
}

let a = ClassA()
a.someFunc()
```

Comment: There's no reference to C in A. A and C both have a reference to B but nothing has a reference to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that the property `b` in `ClassC` holds a strong reference to the instance of `ClassC` that contains it, but that's not true. Properties don't implicitly hold strong references to the thing that contains them. Therefore the local `ClassC` variable created in `someFunc` only stays alive until the end of `someFunc` because nothing is holding a strong reference to it.

Comment: I think that it was my mind was assuming. I realised this was not the case but couldn’t explain why. Thank you for the explanation.